# ASP.NET Core: "The project doesn't know how to run the profile Docker." on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core

I have set up an ASP.Net Core Web application - this application runs `Angular` using `.Net Core 2.2` -> `2.2.0-preview3`. After initializing that project I thought I would have added working docker-support when clicking on "Add" -> "Docker Support" for "Linux Container" - but running this would prompt me with the following error-message:

[image]

Since I *do* have the option to add docker support there should be a way to run Angular in docker, right?

```
Docker Version: 18.09.0
```

Comment: Did you install `Docker for windows` and configure the container with `Linux Container`? What is your vs version? Try to update VS to latest version.

Comment: My VS version is the latest available and I have installed and configured Docker for Windows correctly.

Comment: FYI : If you are still facing this issue : 
I faced the same error today and it worked as expected after restarting Docker for Windows.

Comment: In my case this solved the issue: Close the visual studio then clean the related Docker images.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I know its late already, but it worked for me and i hope it helps.

1 - delete dockerfile present in the project

2 - then right click on the project > add > Docker support

3 - choose between widows or linux

This will recreate the dockerfile and add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets to your nugget dependencies. Updates will maybe be required.

4 - Run and should be just fine

Comment: After following the steps above, I had to restart Visual Studio, then it worked.

Comment: Thanx, I was simply missing the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets package

Answer (score 24):

For me, the nuget package "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" hadn't been resolved. After updating it via Manage NuGet Packages, everything workes perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

In my case a full reboot solved the problem.

Comment: well.. this was the only solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to rebuild the solution, probably to pull in this newly referenced Nuget package in the .csproj:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="x.y.z" />
```

Restarting Visual Studio then running under Docker again was then successful.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if installed Package "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets"
2. The project name and the solution name should be the same, e.g. like WebApp.csproj and WebApp.sln.

Answer (score 0):

I was using VS2019 v16.1.3 and right clicked added an item and selected a Docker File. When clicking the run (Docker) button I encountered this issue. I upgraded to v16.1.5 which also restarted VS2019. Running the application using Docker then worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had all of the sdks installed, however looking at the supported frameworks I could see that the template used netcore2.2. Even though I had it installed, I still got the error. Seeing as 2.2 has reached EndOfLife, so I changed to 2.1

No need to delete the DockerFile

[image: Verify compatible sdk is installed]

The fix for me was to change the FROM build step from 2.2 to 2.1

[image: Updating the DockerFile]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues, resolved by updating NuGet packages to the latest.