# this project doesn't know how to run the profile docker

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, dockerfile, visual-studio-2019

I pull a project from git with dockerfile, I am able to build the image via command line, but the visual studio says "this project doesn't know how to run the profile docker" I am using vs2019. Any pieces of advice?

I have checked this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54485107/1219916 however did not fix my problem

this is my dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-nanoserver-1803 AS base WORKDIR /app EXPOSE 80 EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-nanoserver-1803 AS build WORKDIR /src COPY ["WebApi/WebApi.csproj", "WebApi/"] RUN dotnet restore "WebApi/WebApi.csproj" COPY . . WORKDIR "/src/WebApi" RUN dotnet build "WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish RUN dotnet publish "WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final WORKDIR /app COPY --from=publish /app . ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApi.dll"]
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to get dotnet core SDK and runtime alone, not with nanoserver.
It will fix your issue.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2 AS base WORKDIR /app EXPOSE 80 EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build WORKDIR /src COPY ["WebApi/WebApi.csproj", "WebApi/"] RUN dotnet restore "WebApi/WebApi.csproj" COPY . . WORKDIR "/src/WebApi" RUN dotnet build "WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish RUN dotnet publish "WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final WORKDIR /app COPY --from=publish /app . ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApi.dll"]
```